# React Navigation DeepLinks not working in iOS with AppDelegate.swift

Tags: swift, react-native, react-navigation-v6

In my React Native app, I had to migrate its `AppDelegate` from Objective-C to Swift. After the migration, deeplinks stopped working: when a link is used, the app opens but it does not navigate to the desired route, while in Android it works fine.

Following React Navigation docs, I had this code in my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h> 
// other imports

@implementation AppDelegate

// other stuff

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  if ([[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url options:options]) {
    return YES;
  }

  if ([RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options]) {
    return YES;
  }

  return NO;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray<id<UIUserActivityRestoring>> * _Nullable))restorationHandler
{
 return [RCTLinkingManager application:application
                  continueUserActivity:userActivity
                    restorationHandler:restorationHandler];
}

@end
```

which became the following in Swift:

```
// imports

@main

// other stuff

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open URL: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if (ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: URL, options: options)) {
      return true
    }

    if (RCTLinkingManager.application(application, open: URL, options: options)) {
      return true;
    }

    return false
  }

  func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    return RCTLinkingManager.application(application, continue: userActivity, restorationHandler: restorationHandler)
  }
```

I also have a `myApp-Bridging-Header.h` file:

```
// other imports
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>
```

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong (as I'm pretty lost with Objective-C or Swift) or if deeplinks with an `AppDelegate` written in Swift just don't work.

### Update

The problem seems related with scenes. After adding this code to my PhoneScene, deepLinks work, but only if the app is open or in the background; if it's closed it opens, but in home screen.

```
func scene( _ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    guard let url = URLContexts.first?.url else {
        return
    }

    if RCTLinkingManager.application(UIApplication.shared, open: url, sourceApplication: nil, annotation: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation]) {
        return
    }
  }

  func scene( _ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
      RCTLinkingManager.application(UIApplication.shared, continue: userActivity, restorationHandler: { _ in })
  }
```

Comment: hmm hard to say form what you posted, but this should be in `class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate` - is it? also not sure what `@main` is doing there - did you mean `@UIApplicationMain`? Deep links in swift definitely work though

Comment: Sorry, but I have no experience at all with Swift nor Objective-C. Code is translated from Objective-C to Swift with ChatGPT. I've swapped `@main` with `@UIApplicationMain` but nothing changed.

Comment: my suggestion would be to run proper app generation with RN on the side, and use a generated skeleton for your app, instead of trying to use ChatGPT

Comment: App was generated with RN, but it created an Objective-C AppDelegate. I've been forced to switch to swift due to make a specific library to work.